# EF executes db query before navigation property is accessed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When running the piece of code below, I expect **EF** to execute a db query when **line 3** is reached and then (lazy loading) a second db query when **line 6** is reached. However, when I'm stepping through the code using the debugger, **SQL Server Profiler** shows that the queries are executed at line 3 (as expected) and **line 5** !

How is this possible? Why is the second query executed before the navigation property is accessed on line 6?

```
1. using (var context = new Entities())
2. {
3.     var studentList = context.Students.ToList<Student>();
4.     var student = studentList.ElementAt<Student>(1);
5.     student.StudentName = "Zorro";
6.     var standard = student.Standard;
7. }
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
    [Extent1].[StudentName] AS [StudentName], 
    [Extent1].[StandardId] AS [StandardId], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion]
    FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
```

Query 2:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[StandardId] AS [StandardId], 
    [Extent1].[StandardName] AS [StandardName], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[Standard] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[StandardId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=2
```

[image]

Comment: Paste these at least so that anyone can see the sql.

Comment: is actually the navigation property queried at 5? is the navigation property virtual?

Comment: Remove .tolist(). It will execute the query

Comment: The first query is a select statement that retrieves the list of students. The second one, a select statement that retrieves the details of the Standard.

Comment: In that case you need to provide more info on whats actually getting executed

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL that is being executed? I also believe It's happening because line 5 is the first time you access `student` - your code isn't actually fetching the student from the `studentList` but instead going back to the DB for the single student.

Comment: I have added the SQL queries, as requested.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes, the navigation property is virtual.

Comment: Is it not possible this behavior is due to something VS is doing in the background as part of debugging? If you Sleep the thread between lines 5 and 6 and run it in Release without debugging, does it still behave the same?

Comment: This is a weird behavior indeed. Maybe it does have to do something with ElementAt and the work on DbSet's. Does the same occur when you go with studentlist being an IQueryable (context.Students) and First()?

Answer (score 0):

This question represents everything I hate about lazy loading. Its too easy to do something like this and execute two queries without noticing, where one would have done just fine. Lazy loading makes it easy to miss this.

IMO you should turn it off.

If you want to ensure that you get the `Standard` in your origional DB query you should eager load it like this:

```
var studentList = context.Students.Include(x=>x.Standard).ToList<Student>();
```

On a side not this is going to pull down the whole list of students, you probably want:

```
var student = context.Students.Include(x=>x.Standard).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var student = context.Students.Include(x=>x.Standard).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == 1);
```

to avoid overfetching

Comment: Your answer tells me what your opinion is on lazy loading, which is interesting, but unfortunately it does not answer the question.

Comment: @DiegoDeberdt your problem is that you dont understand what lazy loading is doing. The only option is to eager load if you dont want to do 2 queries with the code you have above. You dont *need* to disable lazy loading to do this, but I would recommend it.

Comment: I think you are trying to help me improve the code sample I provided. But I'm not interested in that. I'm trying to understand why the second query is executed before the navigation property is accessed. The fact that there are 2 queries does not bother me. Therefore, your answer is besides the point.